# how to perform hot backup on Alfresco when Alf_data folder has more than 100GB?

Tags: backup, alfresco

For hot backup, we need to copy the folder content of alf_data right after db backup.
The problem is that the copy of that folder  takes more than 2 hours, in which lot of changes could be made.

Comment: Have you tried some tools like rsync ? It does differential backup, which is a lot faster than copying everything each time.

Comment: Store the data on a ZFS partition and take an almost-instant ZFS-level snapshot? (Other decent filesystems may also exist)